# Load balancing ip conflict in Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

I have  a rb433 connected in pcc to 3 wifi wan routers that all give 192.168.1.1
cant access these routers to change the dhcp
Any sugestions to avoid conflict?

config img here http://postimg.org/image/uis7kq6sn/

thats the working config Here is what i tried http://postimg.org/image/vud5gmb99

vrf with nat wasnt succesful

Anyone Any ideas????
Can i make an ip tunnel or something like that within my router for every wlan and transcend the ip this way??

Answer (score 0):

The right solution is to get the routers to stop using the same exact IP space.

Failing that, you'll need to use VRFs to handle the overlapping routes.  The configuration will look something along the lines of what's discussed in the documentation [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Internet_access_from_VRF_with_NAT).

Comment: @PariGr Which interfaces are the 3 overlapping 192.168.1.0/24 ranges? I only see the one in your config.

Answer (score 0):

Simply disconnect for example wlan2 and wlan3 so that you can access the router on wlan1.

Configure it on a new subnet and then move on to the rest of the wlans until all 3 networks have their own subnet.

Btw, according to your screenshots it doesn't seem to be any subnet overlapping.

Each wlan interface is on a separate subnet. Do I miss something?

Comment: ???I cant access routers as admin and they all need to be at 1.1 First screenshot is an example of working balance at 433